# Search from the beginning of the string. Filter on Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, search, mobile, filter

I read this on the Jquery Mobile Docs:

*If you want to change the way in which list items are filtered, ie fuzzy search or matching from the beginning of the string, you can configure the callback used internally by defining $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.filterCallback during mobileinit or after the widget has been created with $("#mylist").listview('option', 'filterCallback', yourFilterFunction). Any function defined for the callback will be provided two arguments. First, the text of the current list item and second, the value being searched for. A truthy value will result in a hidden list item. The default callback which filters entries without the searchValue as a substring is described below:*

```
function( text, searchValue ){
  return text.toLowerCase().indexOf( searchValue ) === -1;
};
```

But, I haven't been able to understand where do I put this code (I tried making a new .js and import it on my project, but nothing happens), and figure out a way to filter, matching from the beginning of the string.

Any suggestions on this?

Thanks : D

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to do this?

```
$.mobile.listview.prototype.options.filterCallback = function( text, searchValue ){
  return text.toLowerCase().indexOf( searchValue ) === -1;
};
```